# Jquery - setting toggleSlide to slide up on click?

Tags: jquery

I am currently learning jQuery and have set up a toggleSlide effect, at the moment I can only make the hidden content slide down, how can I make the content slide up? When I place the link below the content nothing happens?

http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/EQsVD/

Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just read on the following code

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
div.panel,p.flip
{
margin:0px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.panel
{
height:120px;
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="panel">
<p>Because time is valuable, value the time</p>
<p>time is money, Money is time .</p>
</div>

<p class="flip">Show/Hide Panel</p>

</body>
</html>
```

hope it will help take help from it

Comment: thanks for this, 2 questions though. how can I update this code so that it slides from the bottom up instead of the top down? and also how could I update the toggle so that when you click show the text then changes to hide and vice versa?