# Close ul on parent click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a simple vertical dropdown menu like this:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="">Lorem </a></li>
            <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="">Lorem </a></li>
            <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>  
</nav>
```

I have used simple jquery to open/close child li which works fine, but once the submenu is open, i cant close it by clicking on parent element, instead i need to open other dropdown to close it.

You can see what i mean here : https://jsfiddle.net/1hqkgocr/
I am jquery newbie so i really have no idea on what to do to make it close...

Thank you for any help!

UPDATE: I know that i can just use toggle, but i am having multiple menus in sidebar (wordpress) and i also need to be adding "selected" class to current menu item so this code so far works the best. Only problem, cant close it :D

Comment: you just need to use toggle() function to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - setting toggleSlide to slide up on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934915/jquery-setting-toggleslide-to-slide-up-on-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code by adding `checkElement.slideUp('normal');` as follows:

```
if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.closest('li').removeClass('selected');
    return false;
}
```

Updated code is on https://jsfiddle.net/to27n8dy/1/

```js
          $('nav ul.sub-menu').hide();
          $('nav li.current-menu-item').children().show();
          $('nav li.current-menu-item').parents().show();

          $('nav ul li a').click(
            function() {
              var checkElement = $(this).next();
              if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.closest('li').removeClass('selected');
                return false;
              }
              if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).parent().siblings("li:has(ul)").find("ul").slideUp('normal');
                $('nav ul ul li ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected'); // I also tried .parent().addClass
                return false;
              }
            }
          );
          $('nav ul ul li a').click(
            function() {
              var checkElement = $(this).next();
              if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                return false;
              }
              if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('nav ul ul').slideUp('normal');
                $('nav ul ul li ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
                return false;
              }
            }
          );
```

```css
ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Lorem </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Lorem </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: this works great, thanks, marked accepted :)
if i may, one other thing, this "selected" snippet i used does now work, once i open a menu, it gets "selected" class, but when i close it, class still stays there... any suggestions?

Comment: Add `checkElement.closest('li').removeClass('selected');` after `slideUp`. I've updated my solution with this.

Answer (score 2):

Juste use the `.slideToggle()` JQuery function :

```
$('nav>ul>li').click(function(){
  $('ul',this).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using so much code for a simple task

you just need this:

```js
$('nav ul.sub-menu').hide();
$('nav li.current-menu-item').children().show();
$('nav li.current-menu-item').parents().show(); 

$('nav ul li').click(function() {
  $('.sub-menu',this).slideToggle();
});
```

```css
ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="">Lorem </a></li>
   <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="">Lorem </a></li>
   <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>  
</nav>
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vchmqyg0/

Answer (score 0):

Simple Fix, First give your parent class a class Attribute.

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Next, add this CSS to your sub-menu class, so on default, the sub-menu is not displayed and give it an ID.

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
 }

 <ul class="sub-menu" ID="sub-menu">
```

Then add a show class which changes the display of the contents to block

```
.show {display:block;}
```

Next add jQuery, which toggle the show class

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("sub-menu").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

If you need more help check out: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp